# Update database record by click button without input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to update my database record by clicking on button but without any input field. I want to have something like static var.

```
$scope.test = "test"
```

And I want to put this "test" to the database by clicking on button.

For example:

I have DB table with:

> Id Username State
>
> 1   Test      Open

And after I click on button "update" I want to update my database record - state from "open" -> "close"

I know how to update my DB when I got something from input field:

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="update_id_user">    
<div class="input-field col s3">
  <input ng-model="update_username" type="text" class="validate" placeholder="Username">
</div>
<div class="input-field col s3">
  <input ng-model="update_state" type="text" class="validate" placeholder="State">
</div>
<div class="input-field col s2">
  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue" ng-click="updateuser()"><i class="material-icons right"></i>Update</a>
</div>
```

There is edituser() and update()

```
$scope.edituser = function(id_user) {
$http.post('edit.php',{'id_user' : id_user }
 )      
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {    
      
       
        $scope.update_id_user          =  data[0]["id_user"];
        $scope.update_username        =   data[0]["username"];
        $scope.update_state    =   data[0]["state"];
    })

    .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
       
    });
}

$scope.updateuser = function() {

    $http.post('update.php', 
                {
                    'id_user'     : $scope.update_id_user,
                    'username'     : $scope.update_username, 
                    'state' : $scope.update_state
                }
              )
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {                 
              $scope.getall();
            });
}
```

edit.php file

```
 <?php
require 'conx.php';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));     
$id_user = $data->id_user; 
$result = $db->query("SELECT * from test WHERE id_user='$id_user'");
$d = array();
while($r = $result->fetch_object())
{
    $d[] = array(
                "id_user" =>  $r->id_user,
                "username" => $r->username,
                "state" => $r->state
                );
}
print_r(json_encode($d));
return json_encode($d);
```

update.php file

```
<?php
require 'conx.php';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); 

$id_user = $data->id_user;
$username = $data->username;    
$state = $data->state;
$result = $db->query("UPDATE test SET username='$username' , state='$state'");
```

Main problem is how to set value for example for state that is always set to "close" after click on button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$scope.edituser = edituser;

$scope.user = {
   'id_user' : $scope.update_id_user
}

function edituser() {
        return $http.post('/edit.php', user).then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        });
}
```

Comment: I got an error ReferenceError: id_user is not defined